# How to remove marks from string and turn it into a list

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, split, append

I need to create a function that turns the string to a list without `!?., %#$ .` and without capital letters. The string at the end is just an example so it needs to return `['mr', 'stark', 'i', "don't", 'feel', 'so', 'good']`

Can someone tell me why my code prints `None`?

```
def sentence_to_words(s):
    # Write the rest of the code for question 2 below here.
    s_new= []
    s1 = s.split()
    a = ['#',',','!','.','?','$']
    for i in s.split():
        if i in a:
            s2 = s1.remove(i)
            s_new = s_new.append(s2)
            return s_new
print sentence_to_words("Mr. Stark... I don't feel so good")
```

Comment: what is the issue with your approach?

Comment: it doesn't run on any of the values in the list.. it just prints none

Comment: I don't think your `return` should be inside the `if` statement.

Comment: In `for i in s.split():` you are going through every word of the word and looking if it is in `a`. You should look if the elements of `a` are in `s`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug this is to validate that your assumptions about program state hold on each step. Don't jump ahead until you're sure each line of code does what you expect. Adding a print inside your loop shows exactly what `i` is on each iteration:

```
Mr.
Stark...
I
don't
feel
so
good
```

None of these words are in `a = ['#',',','!','.','?','$']`, so the conditional block inside your loop never runs. After the loop is exhausted, your program returns `None` which Python functions return when no return value is specified.

Furthermore, your conditional block operations aren't working as you expect; check return values and avoid making assignments if they're an in-place operation such as `.append()`, which returns `None` and should not be assigned to anything. Also, if the `if` block does execute, it'll prematurely `return` the result without finishing work on the rest of the list.

You may be looking for something like this:

```
def sentence_to_words(s):
    s_new = []
    ignore = ["#", "!", ",", ".", "?", "$"]

    for word in s.split():
        cleaned_word = ""

        for letter in list(word):
            if letter not in ignore:
                cleaned_word += letter

        s_new.append(cleaned_word.lower())

    return s_new


print sentence_to_words("Mr. Stark... I don't feel so good")
```

Output:

```
['mr', 'stark', 'i', "don't", 'feel', 'so', 'good']
```

The approach in the above example is to iterate over words, then iterate over letters in each word to clean them according to the requirements and add the clean word to the result array. Note the descriptive variable names, which aid in understanding the program (for example, `i` was actually a word in your code, but `i` usually means integer or index).

The above example can be optimized--it uses a lot of error-prone arrays and loops, the ignore list should be a parameter to make the function reusable, and the `in` operator is slow on lists (`ignore` should be a set). Using regex makes it a one-liner:

```
import re

def sentence_to_words(s):
    return re.sub(r"[\#\,\!\.\?\$]", "", s).lower().split()
```

Or using `filter` and the list of characters to ignore as a default parameter:

```
def sentence_to_words(s, ignore=set("#!,.?$")):
    return filter(lambda x: x not in ignore, s).lower().split()
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/PutridJumboCpu)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your code very well, but where's an alternative using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split).
We first remove any special chars with `re.sub` an then use `split` to get a list of words, i.e.:

```
import re
sentence = "Mr. Stark... I don't feel so good"
words = re.sub(r"[#,!\?\$.]", "", s).split()
```

Using `re.split`:

```
words = re.split("[^a-z'-]+", sentence, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
```

---

Both examples output:

```
# ['Mr', 'Stark', 'I', 'don't', 'feel', 'so', 'good']
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/iOcuoS)